# Rails active_model_serializer applied on grouped active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

I am using active_model_serializer from https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers and currently want to apply the serialisation of my model to grouped active records.

I have a model that represents a BlogPost with a title, content and a published date. I use a serializer to format the date into a more user friendly format during serialisation. This works if applied on the active records, however I firstly want to group my BlogPost records to :published and :unpublished like so

```
posts.group_by do |post|
  if post.published_at.nil?
    :unpublished
  else
    :published
  end
end
```

If I render the json output of the grouped data, the serializer is not applied on the BlogPost objects and data gets returned as is.

Does anybody know a way how to apply the serializer on grouped (grouped_by) active records?

Comment: I posted a similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35616592/how-to-use-activemodelserializer-with-group-by/35702760#35702760